# A button that changes the color of an object 3 times

Tags: javascript, browser

I don't seem to have enough knowledge here. I want to make a button that changes the color of an object everytime i click on it. The color should change 3 times and it should loop the whole process. 
Here is what I did:

```
var count = 0;
function myFunction() {
    if (count == 0) {
        character.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
        count = 1;
        console.log(count);
    }
    if  (count == 1) {
        character.style.backgroundColor = "#7FFF00";
        count = 2;
        console.log(count);
    }
    else {
        character.style.backgroundColor = "#A2FAFA";
        count = 0;  
        console.log(count);
    }
}
```

**I know why it doesn't work but I need to write it in another way.**
The funtion changes the color of the object to "#000000" for a splitsecond and goes on to the next color: "#7FFF00". It doesn't end the function after the first "if". How can I rewrite it in another way?

Comment: use `switch case` and `break`, or `return` in each block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fester's answer is quite correct. As an improvement, though, you can keep from repeating code by using an array:

```
var count = 0;
var colours = ["#000000", "#7FFF00", "#A2FAFA"];
function myFunction() {
    count += 1;
    if (count >= colours.length) {
        count = 0;
    }

    character.style.backgroundColor = colours[count];
    console.log(count);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can chain if - else to make sure it won't execute any code after doing the if statement

```
var count = 0;
function myFunction() {
    if (count == 0) {
        character.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
        count = 1;
        console.log(count);
    }
    else if  (count == 1) {
        character.style.backgroundColor = "#7FFF00";
        count = 2;
        console.log(count);
    }
    else {
        character.style.backgroundColor = "#A2FAFA";
        count = 0;  
        console.log(count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The clause continues because you're not using an `else if`. Try this:

```
var count = 0;
function myFunction() {

    count++;
    count = count % 3;

    if (count == 0) character.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";      
    else if  (count == 1)  character.style.backgroundColor = "#7FFF00";       
    else  character.style.backgroundColor = "#A2FAFA";
}
```

I've added a modulo operator as well to simplify your code

Answer (score 0):

For that you should use

```
if(count==0) { ... }
else if(count==1) { ... }
else { ... }
```

**So the function should be**

```
function myFunction() {
    if (count == 0) {
        character.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
        count = 1;
        console.log(count);
    }
    else if  (count == 1) {
        character.style.backgroundColor = "#7FFF00";
        count = 2;
        console.log(count);
    }
    else {
        character.style.backgroundColor = "#A2FAFA";
        count = 0;  
        console.log(count);
    }
}
```

**Better approach:**

```
var count = -1;
function myFunction() {
        var color = ["#000000", "#7FFF00", "#A2FAFA"];
        character.style.backgroundColor = color[count>1?count:++count] ;
}
```

Comment: Your last approach will fail when count reaches 3 and higher.
You need to set count to 0 when count == 3, and use color[count++] instead of color[++count] (or it will start with 1 instead of 0)

Comment: I used the first one with "color[count++]" and  "if (count == 3) {count = 0;}". it worked but your newest version isnt working.                                                  it says         color[count>1?count:++count] ;       what does that mean?